# How to download html source and web contents in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

You can download html source and web contents(.files folder) by right click and "Save As.." in Internet Explorer on PC.
I'd like to do the same way as IE in Windows Phone.

I know how to download html source using WebClient class. But I cannot still download web contents(.files folder).

Does anyone know how to download html source as well as web contents(.files folder) ?

Comment: Save As... in IE on the PC is something built into the browser. You want to know how to do all of that in code? Or you want to know how to do that in the browser.

Comment: why do you want such thing ? Anyways, nothing prevent you to parse the result of webclient download to find links and download them.

Comment: Really thanks your comments. I forgot to write my goal. I'd like to make offline browser application. So I need to save all web contents into IsolatedStorage. I also thought Steve's way. Do you know other solutions ?

Comment: There is no other solutions. So get coding.

Comment: Hi, Claus. Thanks comment. I'm getting coding now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download all the content of a html source and locate contents like images and download them with webclients, you need to code the biggest part of this idea.

here it is a link of an application which allows user to download images from imageboards : 
http://www.windowsphone.com/fr-BE/apps/1d2e7d7c-1bab-4656-9db3-35c868e40cfe